# Understanding GridLayout rows in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, grid-layout

Can someone help me understand the grid layout used in Nativescript, in particular the GridLayout? What does the (star) followed by auto actually mean?

```
<GridLayout rows="*, auto">
```

And then I came across this even more confusing example:

```
<GridLayout rows="*, auto, auto, auto, 2*">
```

I am finding the documentation for the Nativescript not so clear.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation states the following:

> A string value representing row heights delimited with commas. Row
>   heights can be either an `absolute number`, `auto` or `*`. A number
>   indicates an absolute row height, auto makes the row as high as its
>   highest child, and * makes the row occupy all available vertical
>   space.

I think it is important to first distinguish between `auto` and `*`, since they do something different. When you use `auto` as a value, the `GridLayout` will grab the height of the child element with the highest height value and make that the height of the row. So if you have a `GridLayout` with one row containing several columns, one with a height of 20, one with 30 and one with 40, the row will have a height of 40 and columns in that row will match that height.

If you use a `*` instead of `auto` then the `GridLayout` will use all available space for the height of that row. So if the height of your `GridLayout` is 100, the row will also have a height of 100. When you put a number in front of the star, you are basically dividing, so if you have `rows="2*, *"`, the first row will have two thirds of the height of the `GridLayout` and the second row will have one third of the height.

I am not sure if the concept of the `rows` attribute is clear, but to clarify you are defining the height of multiple rows by adding commas, so for example: `<GridLayout rows="*, auto, auto, auto, 2*">` contains the height for five rows. The first and last rows will use the remaining space after the height of the three columns with the `auto` height have been determined.

The NativeScript documentation contains some images to showcase what it looks like, which can be found [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layout-containers#gridlayout-properties).